# what is Database_Default does it mean?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i understand what is collation is.

my question about DATABASE_DEFAULT

is DATABASE_DEFAULT mean the current running database or the Model database ?

imagine that i created a new database then i changed it is collation after creation process if i called this line

```
ON GP_DOCNUMBR COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT = DocumentNumber COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
```

what DATABASE_DEFAULT will be?

Comment: [this answer on MSDN Foruns](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-SG/transactsql/thread/ccd713a3-13a7-4cf8-ab56-1cf3193fa963) gives you what you need.

Comment: that is mean the default database is model database not the current one thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DATABASE_DEFAULT is the collation which you set when the sql server was installed. I always get the default collation of the server by checking the collation of tempdb.

Comment: that is mean the default database is model database not the current one thanks

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to match the msdn documentation linked below which indicates it means the default collation of the current database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx

Comment: Sorry Phil can you help me locate the line which contradicts the answer please?

Comment: In the last line of the arguments section...  "database_default -     Causes the COLLATE clause to inherit the collation of the current database"

Comment: @Phill_P you are right on reading the question again answer feels wrong.

Comment: I only noticed because I was investigating an issue relating to collations today and needed to look this up... in many cases the server instance and database collations will be the same I expect, but it does appear to be the current database collation that is used.

Comment: yes most of the cases it will be same as the Database will have been created from scratch. Places where the Collation has been changed for some reason like the question mentions above. Or where the Database has been restored from other server the collation is different. And i think Hazem must have been comparing the original data (i.e. data before collation was changed hence he must have got the query working)